# convert spark-submit command (dotnet for spark app) to spark-submit command for python app

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit, spark-dotnet

If the following (working) spark-submit command (for a dotnet for Spark app) was executing a python script, would it still use the same --conf settings?  Given a python script name of myapp.py that has no defined function (other than **main**), what would the --class reference be for a python script?

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner \
   --conf "spark.eventLog.enabled=true" \
   --conf "spark.eventLog.dir=file:/usr/bin/spark/hadoop/logs" \
   --master spark://spark:7077 \
   /opt/spark/jars/microsoft-spark-3-1_2.12-2.0.0.jar \
   dotnet myapp.dll "somefilename.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python applications, simply pass a .py file, no need to mention the class name

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \    
--conf "spark.eventLog.enabled=true" \
--conf "spark.eventLog.dir=file:/usr/bin/spark/hadoop/logs" \   
--master spark://spark:7077 \
/your python file path/myapp.py
```

For further info, you can refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: Would it be the same, functionally, if, for whatever reason, trying to execute the .py script only worked when calling it via, "python myapp.py"?

```/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \    
--conf "spark.eventLog.enabled=true" \
--conf "spark.eventLog.dir=file:/usr/bin/spark/hadoop/logs" \   
--master spark://spark:7077 \
python  /pathtofile/myapp.py```

Comment: dont use python, spark-submit will automatically run myapp.py file

Comment: Thank you @Sri_Karthik